# Firefox web extension override newtab page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to do something like this in my webextension inside background script for firefox 52 browser :

```
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/NewTabURL.jsm");
NewTabURL.override(value);
```

But firefox says that Components.utils - undefined .
My extension based on chrome , so i need to use web extension addon type (. 
Is it possible to override newtab page in other way before Firefox 54 realize ?

Update : here is my little code which helps me did newtab replace , but it buggy (

```
var newTabUrl = browser.extension.getURL("../index.html");

    function handleActivated(activeInfo) {
        console.log("Tab ", activeInfo);
        if (activeInfo.url === "about:newtab") {
            browser.tabs.update(activeInfo.id, {
                url: newTabUrl
            });
        }
    }

    var querying = browser.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    });

    const newtabdemo = {
        getActiveTab: function() {
            return browser.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            });
        },

        openNewTabPage: function() {
            newtabdemo.getActiveTab().then((tab) => {
                var gettingInfo = browser.tabs.get(tab[0].id);
                gettingInfo.then(handleActivated);

            });
        }
    };

    browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(newtabdemo.openNewTabPage);
```

Comment: `Components.utils` (e.g. `Components.utils.import`) is not part of WebExtensions. Remove it, and forget about it. Don't try to use anything connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create chrome override page for the `newtab` page.

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides

Example:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
  "newtab": "my-new-tab.html"
}
```

Comment: it's not aviable to use till Firefox 54 .  (

Comment: it's fine for chrome , but not for ff yet

Comment: until Firefox 54 then there is no way to do this with a web extension, you'd have to use an old school add-on until Fx54